# How can i draw out shapes in circle with python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am learning python, and I cant figure out this simple task. I have a code sample with text, I need to do the same, but not with text, but some shapes (I need flags now -> see the image below).

Thank you for any solutions!

My code:

```
 import tkinter
 import random

 canvas = tkinter.Canvas(height = 500, width = 500, background = 'white')
 canvas.pack()


 for i in range(12):
      canvas.create_text(250,250, text = 20*' '+'Python', font = 'Arial 25', angle = i*30)


 tkinter.mainloop()
```

I need this result from the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hb8W.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out on my own...if someone ever needs this:

```
import tkinter
import random
import math

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(height = 500, width = 500, background = 'white')
canvas.pack()

length = 150
Angle = 15

RadAngle = math.pi/180*Angle #degree in radians to use it with cos and sin



for i in range(24):
     canvas.create_line(250,250,250+math.cos(i*RadAngle)*length,250+math.sin(i*RadAngle)*length,\
                        250+math.cos((i+1)*RadAngle)*(length-25),250+math.sin((i+1)*RadAngle)*(length-25),\
                        250+math.cos(i*RadAngle)*(length-50),250+math.sin(i*RadAngle)*(length-50))

tkinter.mainloop()
```